# JFrame is always slightly to the right

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi so I am making a logging application. Whenever I use pack() on JFrame() it always ends up being slightly to the right of my screen as you can see in the photo. If I use setLocation(-10, 0) I can fix this however, I don't really like this solution and I want my application to work on different screen resolutions. Is there any other way to fix this? Thanks.

Slightly off JFrame:

ht[image: tps://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ7X0.png]

Minimum reproducible example:

```
public class LogMonitor extends JFrame {
public LogMonitor() {
    setTitle("Log Monitor");
    screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Dimension newDi = new Dimension((int) Math.round(screenSize.width), (int) Math.round(screenSize.height*0.80));
    //setSize((int) Math.round(screenSize.width), (int) Math.round(screenSize.height*0.80));
    overallPanelSetup();
    createFilterSection();
    createLogTable("ALL", "20");
    add(overallPanel);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: After pack and before `setVisible(true)` do `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)`.  That should center it on the screen.  And it is bad technique to extend `JFrame`. Just use an instance.

Comment: @WJS Unfortunately that didn't work. It just moved the window down.
https://imgur.com/a/nmsiWJO

Comment: This is not a reproducible example

Comment: The example is minimal but not complete nor reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it always ends up being slightly to the right of my screen

I believe this is an issue when using Swing on Windows 10.

> If I use setLocation(-10, 0)...

That is the standard solution.

If you want a full screen window than you can use:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```